# Typo3 validator returns Call to a member function addError() on null

Tags: model-view-controller, typo3, extbase

I have a fluid form.On completion of edit an ajax call is passed to controller
i make an instance of **EmailAddressValidator()** My code is given below

```
$validate =  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Validation\\Validator\\EmailAddressValidator');
$result = $validate->isValid('xyz@gmail.com');
```

It returns nothing if the email is in correct format.But it returns

> **Call to a member function addError()**

if the format is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated)

The problem is how you call the validator. You need to call the method `validate`, not `isValid`.

So this should work:

```
$validate =  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Validation\\Validator\\EmailAddressValidator');
$result = $validate->validate('xyz@gmail.com');
```

`$result` is an instance of [`TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Result`](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_error_1_1_result.html), you can use the method `hasErrors` on it to check if the mail was valid.

Comment: TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager could not start with back slash.So I removed the back slashesh and run the code .But same issue exists.

Comment: Ok, you're right... the problem is not with DI in this case (which is ususally/often the problem when calling a member on `null`), but how you call the validator... I'll edit the answer.

Comment: My new code is :     $validate =  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Validation\\Validator\\EmailAddressValidator');
       
       $result = $validate->isValid('xyzgmail.com');
       $error = $result->hasError();     But the same error occurs

Comment: You need to call `validate`, not `isValid`: `$result = $validate->validate(...)`. `validate` calls `isValid` internally, but creates the `$result` before doing so, which `isValid` then uses.

Comment: Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Result::hasError()

Comment: It's `hasErrors` (fixed it in the answer), in plural - check the link in the answer, you can also get error messages from it.

Comment: My $result object is

TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Resultprototypeobject
   errors => array(empty)
   errorsExist => FALSE
   warnings => array(empty)
   warningsExist => FALSE
   notices => array(empty)
   noticesExist => FALSE
   propertyResults => array(empty)
   parent => NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116754/discussion-between-aswathy-s-and-jost).